# How to create posts-by-month-and-year table in Jekyll without plugins?

Tags: jekyll

I want to create a table counting posts by month and year in a Jekyll blog (and linking to the first in each group), *without* using any plugins (because GitHub won't run them). http://software-carpentry.org/blog/archives.html#all-posts is what I'm trying to reproduce; I'd be grateful for pointers.

Comment: This post is beeing discussed on Meta, so any irregular voting patterns are most likely due to that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311428/failed-close-audit-and-i-dont-understand-why

Comment: It's a shame you can't just scream "I give up, stop giving me down votes because I wish I can delete my question but the software won't let me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for the `archive.html` page. You can see it [live here](http://pygmeeweb.com/jekyllBoilerplate/archive/).

Tested with 400 posts, no performance issues on build/serve.

```
---
layout: page
title: archive
---

{%comment%} ++++++++++ We first find start and end years ++++++++++ {%endcomment%}
{% assign startYear = 2222 %}
{% assign endYear   = 1 %}

{% for post in site.posts %}
  {%comment%} +++++
    "| plus: 0" casts postYear to fixnum, because "post.date | date: "%Y"" is a string
    and comparing "2013" with 2012 (string / number) throws an error
  +++++ {%endcomment%}
  {% assign postYear = post.date | date: "%Y" | plus: 0 %}

  {% if postYear > endYear %}{% assign endYear = postYear %}{% endif %}
  {% if postYear < startYear %}{% assign startYear = postYear %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{%comment%} +++++++++++++++ build the table +++++++++++++++ {%endcomment%}

{% assign tableContent = "<tr><th></th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th></tr>" %}

{%comment%} +++++
  currentPostIndex is used to loop over post in an efficient way
  Knowing that posts a sorted by date, we don't need to loop over
  all posts each time we want to inspect them.
  Instead we only loop through posts we don't already inspect.
+++++ {%endcomment%}
{% assign currentPostIndex = 0 %}

{%comment%} +++++ site.posts array is zero numbered, so last index = size-1 +++++ {%endcomment%}
{% assign lastPostIndex = site.posts.size | minus: 1 %}

{%comment%} +++++ Looping trough years in REVERSE order +++++ {%endcomment%}
{% for year in (startYear...endYear) reversed %}

  {% assign yearRow = "<tr><th>" | append: year | append: "</th>" %}

  {%comment%} +++++ Trick to create an empty array +++++ {%endcomment%}
  {% assign yearCellsArray = "" | split: "/" %}

  {%comment%} +++++ Looping over month reversed +++++ {%endcomment%}
  {% for month in (1...12) reversed %}

    {% assign postsThisYearMonth = 0 %}
    {% assign monthCell = "<td>" %}

    {% for postIndex in (currentPostIndex...lastPostIndex) %}

      {% assign p      = site.posts[postIndex] %}
      {% assign pYear  = p.date | date: "%Y" | plus: 0 %}
      {% assign pMonth = p.date | date: "%m" | plus: 0 %}

      {% if pYear == year and pMonth == month %}
        {% assign postsThisYearMonth = postsThisYearMonth | plus: 1 %}
      {% else %}
        {%comment%} +++++ Here we stop the loop +++++ {%endcomment%}
        {% assign currentPostIndex = postIndex %}
        {% break %}
      {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    {% if postsThisYearMonth > 0 %}
      {% assign linkTargetId = "#" | append: year | append: "-" | append: month %}
      {% assign linkStart    = "<a href='" | append: linkTargetId | append: "'>" %}
      {% assign linkEnd      = "</a>" %}
      {% assign cellContent  = linkStart | append: postsThisYearMonth | append: linkEnd %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign cellContent  = "&nbsp" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% assign monthCell = monthCell | append: cellContent | append: "</td>" %}
    {% assign yearCellsArray = yearCellsArray | unshift: monthCell %}

  {% endfor %}

  {% assign yearCells = yearCellsArray | join: "" %}
  {% assign yearRow = yearRow | append: yearCells | append: "</tr>" %}
  {% assign tableContent = tableContent | append: yearRow %}

{% endfor %}

<h2>All Posts By Date</h2>
<table class="table table-striped blogcalendar">
  <tbody>
    {{ tableContent }}
  </tbody>
</table>

{%comment%} +++++ Printing posts by Year then month +++++ {%endcomment%}

{% assign currentPostIndex = 0 %}
{% assign lastPostIndex = site.posts.size | minus: 1 %}

{% for year in (startYear...endYear) reversed %}
  <h3>{{year}}</h3>
  {% assign currentYear = year %}
  {% for month in (1...12) reversed %}

    {% assign postsArray = "" | split: "/" %}

    {%comment%} +++++ Find post for this year / month +++++ {%endcomment%}
    {% for postIndex in (currentPostIndex...lastPostIndex) %}
      {% assign p      = site.posts[postIndex] %}
      {% assign pYear  = p.date | date: "%Y" | plus: 0 %}
      {% assign pMonth = p.date | date: "%m" | plus: 0 %}

      {% if pYear == year and pMonth == month %}
        {% assign postsArray = postsArray | push: p %}
      {% else %}
        {%comment%} +++++ Here we stop the loop +++++ {%endcomment%}
        {% assign currentPostIndex = postIndex %}
        {% break %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% assign postArraySize = postsArray | size %}

    {%comment%} +++++ Printing posts if we have some for this year month +++++ {%endcomment%}
    {% if postArraySize and postArraySize > 0 %}

      {%comment%} +++++ get month name from a post.date +++++ {%endcomment%}
      {% assign post = postsArray | first %}
      {% assign monthName = post.date | date: "%B" %}

      {% assign monthId = year | append: "-" | append: month %}

      <h4 id="{{ monthId }}">{{ monthName }} {{ year }}</h4>
      <table class="table table-striped">
      {% for p in postsArray %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ p.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}</td>
          <td>
              <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">
                  {{ p.title }}
              </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </table>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @DavidJacquel Probably because people think you shouldn't have replied. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311428/failed-close-audit-and-i-dont-understand-why/311429#311429

Comment: Thank you @KeithM. And I can tell you that I'm proud of this answer. I get a job with it !